# IDEA Play 2.3 console not working

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I started creating a project with Play Framework 2.3 in Intellij IDEA. In this project I need to have an embedded database. The built-in-database for Play is H2. To browse the database I need to type "h2-browser" in play console. BUT: I can't open the play console. I tried to type "play", "activator", "sbt" in terminal in path of my project, but get only that command not found.

This is my build.sbt:

```
name := "helpies"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `helpies` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc ,
  javaEbean ,
  cache ,
  javaWs,
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
  "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1-2",
  "org.webjars" % "flat-ui" % "bcaf2de95e"
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.9.Final"
)

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )
```

EDIT: I realized, that I created my project without typesafe activator. Is there any way to import my project in activator or I have only possibility to create a new app with activator? I don't find the answer in activator's docs. Or is there any possibility to start play console without activator?

Comment: Do you have path to you `activator.bat` location added to you system's PATH environmental variable?

Comment: I don't find 'activator.bat' at all

Comment: http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.4/typesafe-activator-1.3.4.zip

Comment: I created my project without activator, just with play framework. How can I import my project in activator?

Comment: You don't have to import. Just download the activator, unzip it somewhere and add path to `activator.bat` to your system's PATH.

Comment: I did it. It allows me to create new project. "play", "h2-browser", "sbt" are still unknown in activator's folder and in project folder. In the UI of activator there are no "import existing project" menu.

Comment: There is no more `play` command. To enter console use `activator` command in you project's folder.

Comment: Command "activator" is not found too. Even after I downloaded activator, extracted and run them, added them to PATH. This command works only in folder of activator and starts README.HTML file.

Comment: Try rebooting your system? It's now not an issue of Play Framework.

Comment: Didn't help. I think, it's because the project was created without activator. I created a new project via activator and there the command "activator" works fine. But in my old project still not.